# Conditional mean of column by group to all rows on data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have the following data

```
DT <- data.table(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3),
                bank=c("a","b","b","b","b","a","b"),
                rate =c(2,3,4,1,0.5,7,3.2),
                balance=c(10,5,11,3,20,0.5,2),
                new=c(1,0,0,1,0,0,1),
                before=c(1,0,1,1,0,1,0))

    id bank rate balance new before
1:  1    a  2.0    10.0   1      1
2:  1    b  3.0     5.0   0      0
3:  1    b  4.0    11.0   0      1
4:  2    b  1.0     3.0   1      1
5:  2    b  0.5    20.0   0      0
6:  3    a  7.0     0.5   0      1
7:  3    b  3.2     2.0   1      0
```

I want to add a column with the mean rate of new loans (new==1) by bank to all rows. Best I have neem able to do is

```
aft <- DT[new==1,.(mrate=mean(rate)),by=bank]
aft <-  merge(DT,aft, by="bank", all.x = T)

   bank id rate balance new before mrate
1:    a  1  2.0    10.0   1      1   2.0
2:    a  3  7.0     0.5   0      1   2.0
3:    b  1  3.0     5.0   0      0   2.1
4:    b  1  4.0    11.0   0      1   2.1
5:    b  2  1.0     3.0   1      1   2.1
6:    b  2  0.5    20.0   0      0   2.1
7:    b  3  3.2     2.0   1      0   2.1
```

Is there a way that avoids the merge step. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I answered your question, Zentaur, but as I look at your history, I see that you have [previously asked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2792234/zentaur?tab=questions) with reasonable answers, and you have chosen to not accept them. While this is your right, I think many potential answerers will look at this _before_ answering your question and choose to not help somebody who provides no palpable gratitude. I'm not attempting to coerce you to accept my answer below, that's your right, but know that not accepting is counter-culture on Stack sites.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I didn't even know you could do that. I just upvoted. Silly me.

Comment: Thanks Zentaur, I appreciate both the acceptance and more importantly adopting a "norm" on Stack sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
DT[, mrate := mean(rate[new == 1]), by = .(bank)]
#       id   bank  rate balance   new before mrate
#    <num> <char> <num>   <num> <num>  <num> <num>
# 1:     1      a   2.0    10.0     1      1   2.0
# 2:     1      b   3.0     5.0     0      0   2.1
# 3:     1      b   4.0    11.0     0      1   2.1
# 4:     2      b   1.0     3.0     1      1   2.1
# 5:     2      b   0.5    20.0     0      0   2.1
# 6:     3      a   7.0     0.5     0      1   2.0
# 7:     3      b   3.2     2.0     1      0   2.1
```

If there's a change that a bank has no `new == 1` rows, then you will get `NaN`s:

```r
DT[1,new:=0]
DT[, mrate := mean(rate[new == 1]), by = .(bank)]
#       id   bank  rate balance   new before mrate
#    <num> <char> <num>   <num> <num>  <num> <num>
# 1:     1      a   2.0    10.0     0      1   NaN
# 2:     1      b   3.0     5.0     0      0   2.1
# 3:     1      b   4.0    11.0     0      1   2.1
# 4:     2      b   1.0     3.0     1      1   2.1
# 5:     2      b   0.5    20.0     0      0   2.1
# 6:     3      a   7.0     0.5     0      1   NaN
# 7:     3      b   3.2     2.0     1      0   2.1
```

If this is a problem, you can use `fcoalesce` around the mean to specify a default value; I'll use `-1` here just to be clear what I'm talking about:

```r
DT[, mrate := fcoalesce(mean(rate[new == 1]), -1), by = .(bank)]
#       id   bank  rate balance   new before mrate
#    <num> <char> <num>   <num> <num>  <num> <num>
# 1:     1      a   2.0    10.0     0      1  -1.0
# 2:     1      b   3.0     5.0     0      0   2.1
# 3:     1      b   4.0    11.0     0      1   2.1
# 4:     2      b   1.0     3.0     1      1   2.1
# 5:     2      b   0.5    20.0     0      0   2.1
# 6:     3      a   7.0     0.5     0      1  -1.0
# 7:     3      b   3.2     2.0     1      0   2.1
```